# Pandas: can't create pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataframe:

```
    test_num  file_num    dose  is_anneal  test_name  fail
0         10         0    0.00      False    test1       
1         10         1   10.42      False    test1       
2         10         2   34.34      False    test1       
3         10         3   57.06      False    test1       
4         10         4  103.45      False    test1       
5         10         5  200.69      False    test1       
6         10         6  300.24      False    test1     8↑
7         11         0    0.00      False    test2       
8         11         1   10.42      False    test2       
9         11         2   34.34      False    test2       
10        11         3   57.06      False    test2     2↑
11        11         4  103.45      False    test2     2↑
12        11         5  200.69      False    test2     2↑
13        11         6  300.24      False    test2  2↑,8↑
```

I want to make a pivot table so that both `test_num` and `test_name` could present:

```
fail_data_pivot = fd.pivot(columns='dose', index=['test_num', 'test_name'], values='fail')

>>ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 14, placement implies 2

fail_data_pivot = fd.pivot_table(columns='dose', index=['test_num', 'test_name'], values='fail')

>>pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

If I left only `test_num`  then it works:

```
fail_data_pivot = fd.pivot(columns='dose', index='test_num', values='fail')
print(fail_data_pivot)

dose     0.00   10.42  34.34  57.06  103.45 200.69 300.24
test_num                                                 
10                                                     8↑
11                                2↑     2↑     2↑  2↑,8↑
```

This is what I want instead:

```
dose                   0.00   10.42  34.34  57.06  103.45 200.69 300.24
test_num  test_name                                               
10        test1                                                     8↑
11        test2                                2↑     2↑     2↑  2↑,8↑
```

How to make a pivot table with multiple index?

Comment: you should using pivot_table with aggfunc, not pivot

Comment: @WeNYoBen Which aggregate function should I use?

Comment: aggfunc=','.join

Comment: @WeNYoBen But values are already joined

Comment: @May I know why you need two same key ['test_num', 'test_name'] ?

Comment: @WeNYoBen There can be tests with same name but different numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said you can using `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(columns='dose', index=['test_num', 'test_name'], values='fail',aggfunc='first')
```